# Unit Test doesn't receive return value from referenced project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a program that decodes given text. It works like it should. I created a Unit Test and referenced the project. The thing is, it fails the test where it checks if the result is equal with the expected result, but when I run the project, the result is the expected one.

I debugged it and it turns out that it doesn't receive the return value of the string from the referenced project. It receives the encrypted one. And it says that the elements of the Encode class are not public, and they are.

I didn't include the Encode class, since I don't have a problem with that one. It's public static if that matters. The test is what's not working. 
Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?
Why it says that they are not public, when they are?

Comment: You didn't show your Encode function

Comment: I posted the function too, if that helps.

Comment: Can you post the enclosing class too, the function looks OK

Comment: Sorry, the enclosing class? I have only the encode and the main in this project.

Comment: And yes, the function works but when it is called from the unit test it seems to not send the result because like it says they are non public members. I just don't know where to change that since it says public class. 

And also, I can't make any changes in the unit test project, since that was given to me, I had to make the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your Key is upper case and your strings are lower case. So the statements

```
if (key[j] == toEncrypt[i])
```

and

```
else if (key[j+1] == toEncrypt[i])
```

will never be true, you should `.ToLower()` your key in the function

Edit:

```
public static Tuple<string, int[]> Encode(string key, string toEncrypt)
{
    key = key.ToLower();
    int[] iterations = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    if (key.Length % 2 == 0)
    { 
        if (key.Length == key.Distinct().Count())
        {
            var encodedText = new StringBuilder(toEncrypt);
            for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.Length ; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j += 2)
                {

                    if (key[j] == toEncrypt[i])
                    {
                        encodedText[i] = key[j + 1];
                        iterations[j / 2] += 1;

                    }
                    else if (key[j+1] == toEncrypt[i])
                    {
                        encodedText[i] = key[j];
                        iterations[j / 2] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return Tuple.Create(encodedText.ToString(), iterations);
        }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Key cannot contain the same chars");
    }
    else throw new ArgumentException("You have to put a key which is dividable by 2");
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. The test passed now. Thank you so much.